# Finding all clusters of coordinates where each coordinate in a cluster is separated from one another by less than some maximum distance

Tags: python, recursion, nested, cluster-analysis, permutation

I have this set of coordinates:

```
[[211,76], [235,84], [240,88], [300,79], [230,100], [203,110], [202,95], [203,98], [214,97], [248,137], [249,111], [282,120], [263,144], [245,167], [192,172], [124,161], [322,146], [338,142], [355,146], [322,90], [343,105], [363,105], [368,116], [349,83], [348,67], [348,56], [390,75], [327,69], [443,73], [363,96], [396,104], [467,87], [499,87], [197,201], [199,200], [229,201], [227,219], [243,235], [403,166], [370,189], [399,212], [408,227], [214,292], [297,236], [352,276], [430,304], [437,348], [457,347], [430,277], [459,317], [709,153], [772,113], [828,103], [758,308], [767,320], [771,325], [803,330], [778,346], [795,348], [808,341], [834,341], [831,359], [762,391], [764,402], [817,404], [844,426], [827,440], [862,467], [729,433], [732,449], [747,477], [767,480], [657,454], [647,468], [649,467], [626,480], [670,499], [645,524], [652,547], [649,562], [688,566], [580,645], [580,645], [387,632], [419,625], [417,617], [419,614], [575,419]]
```

I want to find all clusters of coordinates where each coordinate in a cluster is separated from one another by less than a maximum distance of 215.05813167606567.

I have thought about if you could choose a coordinate and then add it to an empty list. Then choose a second coordinate and if it is separated in distance from every coordinate already in such list by less than 215.05813167606567, add it to the list directly after the existing coordinates. Then choose a third coordinate and repeat, adding it to the list directly after the existing coordinates if it is separated from every coordinate already in the list by less than 215.05813167606567. There would be eventually 88 coordinates chosen as there are 88 coordinates total, some of which not making it to the list. There are 88! ways that the 88 points can be chosen as doing this process is a permutation with n=88 and r=88. Then if there hasn't been a list generated already of coordinates separated by less than a max distance of 215.05813167606567 which are the same but only have been chosen in a different order, then the newly generated list, with only coordinates separated by a max distance of 215.05813167606567, gets saved to a variable.

I have tried generating each of the 88! permutations, for which to perform the aforementioned process of conditionally adding each coordinate to another list, with 88 nested for-loops in Python but it does not work and I don't know how else to do it.

```
elements = [[211,76], [235,84], [240,88], [300,79], [230,100], [203,110], [202,95], [203,98], [214,97], [248,137], [249,111], [282,120], [263,144], [245,167], [192,172], [124,161], [322,146], [338,142], [355,146], [322,90], [343,105], [363,105], [368,116], [349,83], [348,67], [348,56], [390,75], [327,69], [443,73], [363,96], [396,104], [467,87], [499,87], [197,201], [199,200], [229,201], [227,219], [243,235], [403,166], [370,189], [399,212], [408,227], [214,292], [297,236], [352,276], [430,304], [437,348], [457,347], [430,277], [459,317], [709,153], [772,113], [828,103], [758,308], [767,320], [771,325], [803,330], [778,346], [795,348], [808,341], [834,341], [831,359], [762,391], [764,402], [817,404], [844,426], [827,440], [862,467], [729,433], [732,449], [747,477], [767,480], [657,454], [647,468], [649,467], [626,480], [670,499], [645,524], [652,547], [649,562], [688,566], [580,645], [580,645], [387,632], [419,625], [417,617], [419,614], [575,419]]
for x1 in elements:
    tempelements1 = elements.copy()
    tempelements1.remove(x1)
    for x2 in tempelements1:
        tempelements2 = tempelements1.copy()
        tempelements2.remove(x2)
        for x3 in tempelements2:
            tempelements3 = tempelements2.copy()
            tempelements3.remove(x3)
            for x4 in tempelements3:
                tempelements4 = tempelements3.copy()
                tempelements4.remove(x4)
                for x5 in tempelements4:
                    tempelements5 = tempelements4.copy()
                    tempelements5.remove(x5)
                    #...
                        for x88 in tempelements87:
                            permutations = [x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, x17, x18, x19, x20, x21, x22, x23, x24, x25, x26, x27, x28, x29, x30, x31, x32, x33, x34, x35, x36, x37, x38, x39, x40, x41, x42, x43, x44, x45, x46, x47, x48, x49, x50, x51, x52, x53, x54, x55, x56, x57, x58, x59, x60, x61, x62, x63, x64, x65, x66, x67, x68, x69, x70, x71, x72, x73, x74, x75, x76, x77, x78, x79, x80, x81, x82, x83, x84, x85, x86, x87, x88]
                            # 'permutations' is the variable that gets re-assigned one
                            # after another every permutation of the list of 88 coordinates
```

Comment: "I have tried generating each of the 88! permutations" Really? Even with 1 million calculations per second you'd need almost 6E120 years to compute!

Comment: @tonypdmtr I just meant that I tried running the code and it didn't work

Comment: And I meant that if you were to even try this approach you'd be up for a very long wait.  Could you possibly mean 88^2?

Comment: @tonypdmtr No but I'm just trying to find all clusters in which every coordinate is separated by one another by a distance between 0 and 215.05813167606567.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the problem, it sounds like having to compute the distance of each coordinate (88 of them) with each of the remaining ones (87 of them).  That would be 88*87 total calculations.  And if you consider that past the half point you will have already found the distance (i.e. pair 1-88 is the same as pair 88-1), you need somewhere near 88*87/2 = 3828 calculations.

Comment: @tonypdmtr--actually he's trying to find a good way to clustering the points such that the max distance of a point from its cluster center is less than 215.058...A popular method is [Kmeans clustering](https://sites.google.com/site/dataclusteringalgorithms/k-means-clustering-algorithm).  The tricky part is the points are Lat/Lon so a transformations need to be bad to find distances between points, i.e. [haversine distance](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

Comment: @tonypdmtr You are referring to combinations with n=88 and r=2 but I'm trying to find all combinations with n=88 for each r from r=1 to r=88 and I want to discard all combinations if they fully contained within other combinations with higher r.

Comment: Since Latitudes range from 0 to 90 and Longitudes range from 0 to 180 what are the unit of the coordinates you're using (i.e. can't be lat/long)?  Are they just rectangular coordinates?

Comment: @DarryIG I just opened this image (https://imgur.com/a/DokmrLF) in MS Paint and just used the coordinates that it labels for pixels. The top-leftmost pixel in an image in MS Paint has the coordinate (0, 0). Going from left to right increases the x-coordinate from 0 onward and going from top to bottom increases the y-coordinate from 0 onward.

Comment: @DarryIG For a cluster of coordinates to all be separated from one another by less than a maximum distance, every circle at the center of each coordinate in a cluster with a radius of the maximum distance must overlap with each other at some region. The number of overlapping regions should be manageable. I think I will iterate through coordinates that are spaced enough from each other that they all cover every overlapping region and check to see which coordinates belong to the circles that produced the overlapping region the iterated coordinate is in. Then discard duplicate clusters...

Comment: @DarryIG ...and clusters that are fully contained in larger clusters so that if there were a cluster of points A and B and another of points A, B, and C, then the cluster of A and B would be discarded.

Comment: It is refreshing to think about circles because I was thinking about permutations and such until now which apparently leads to a dead-end.